Wordpress themes and pages broken
I used to build low to middle class websites using wordpress. Its been about two years (went to cyber security and Networking) and I had a friend of mine ask me if he could set up a landing page, simple enough right. WEELLLLLLLL, no.
So my issue is, I have my theme (and I have tried other themes, browsers, etc.), but one, I am missing the demo content (the demo pages that usually fill the page section). Fair enough right? Just make a new and use a template right? Again, wrong apparently. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I have never had this issue in the past when I did work on websites. The only thing I never did was set accounts up, connecting to hosting, etc. Boss usually did that, but I usually did everything from finding a new theme to designing and building a complete site, and this has never been an issue. I have never run into this before. I can, "visit site" from dashboard > edit > then it takes me to what I am assuming is the block editor for the template, but not the page itself, because there are no pages under pages in the dashboard.
